# Shopify Asset URL Error

Tags: html, shopify

I am trying to use asset url,

`{{'Archt-Quick-Start-Guide-FR.jpg' | asset_url }}`

but after saving the page its converting it to this, like encoded in URI,

`%7B%7B'Archt-Quick-Start-Guide-FR.jpg'%20%7C%20asset_url%7D%7D`.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a liquid code in the "Page" on Shopify. It will just treat it as another html object. You can instead do the following in the `Shopify -> Admin Panel -> Online Store -> Themes -> Edit HTML/CSS`

1. Click on *Add a new template* under **Templates**
2. Select "Create a new template for *page*" and give it a name.
3. In this newly created template, add your code and load it into a JS variable right at the start of the page. `<script>var test = '{{ 'Archt-Quick-Start-Guide-FR.jpg' | asset_url }}'</script>`
4. This will load the link of the image into test.
5. Next, go to the page you are editing under `Shopify -> Admin Panel -> Online Store -> Pages -> Your Page`
6. Now use JavaScript function to load the *"test"* variable into the element as required.

Comment: Can you explain more on the 6th part. I would appreciate it if you could show me an example of loading the 'test' variable'. Thank you very much!

Comment: Lets say you have an image with with id as 'my_shopify_asset_test'. The element would be like this - `<div id="my_shopify_asset_test"><img src="" alt="...." ... /></div>`

All you need to do is load test value into this _src_ like this using javascript/jquery - 
`<script>(function(){$('#my_shopify_asset_test img').attr('src',test)})</script>`

Add this script line immediately after the required **<div>** to load the image immediately.

Comment: I managed to solve it before reading this. Haha. But this is almost the same. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a standard page from Online Store > Pages or are you editing a theme file?

Try this:

```
{{ 'Archt-Quick-Start-Guide-FR.jpg' | asset_url | img_tag }}
```

Comment: I'm using Online Store > Pages. Will try this out. What about if its a pdf file?

Comment: Hey its still encoding URI. Is it because I'm using a standard page from Online Store > Pages? @Trees